# ionic 3 input field rounded corner and icon

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on an ionic 3 mobile app in which I had to design a login page with input fields which have an icon in the left and with rounded corners. But someone in ionic decided that people don't need borders for input elements anymore and they made all the input styles as underlined.

I tried so many ways to accomplish it but I couldn't pull it off. If I use custom elements instead of ionic ones I can get the layout but it messes with responsive design and especially with the keyboard, keyboards don't come up.

Can anyone help me on this? is my markup.

```
 <ion-content padding>
      <div text-center class="logo-container">
      <img class="login-logo" src="./assets/imgs/clean_connect.png" alt="Logo of clean connect">
        <h4>Sign in to your account</h4>
      </div>
      <form [formGroup]="signInForm" (submit) = "login(signInForm.value)" novalidate>
        <ion-list>  

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label><ion-icon name="ios-person-outline" item-left></ion-icon></ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" value="agira" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item no-lines  *ngIf="!signInForm.controls.username.valid && (signInForm.controls.username.dirty)">
          <div>
            Please enter valid Username
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label><ion-icon name="ios-lock-outline" item-left></ion-icon></ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" value="Agira1" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item no-lines *ngIf="!signInForm.controls.password.valid && (signInForm.controls.password.dirty)">
          <div>
            Please enter Password
          </div>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <button class="sign-in" type="submit" ion-button full favourite [disabled]="!signInForm.valid">Sign In</button>
      </form>
    </ion-content>
```

Comment: you could add custom classes and design it..

Comment: @SurajRao is there any examples I can follow, I mean I tried a lot of things and each had some issues. Have you done it with ionic 3 before?

Comment: I think you have to use the ion-input components, but change their style.

Comment: In your ion-input tag try to use custom css class as @SurajRao mentioned.
Like in your sass file for the page, write something
`.custom-css{
   border: 1px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border-color: red;
}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I made it:

```
ion-item:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  ion-item:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  ion-item.item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    .label {
      width: 10%;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }
  }
```

You can get something like this:

[image: Round and transparent inputs - image]

Probably you'll need to use class names instead of the *ion-item* directly...

Answer (score 5):

i have make it in my project here is the code, this code makes your `ion-input` rounded. 
I hope this works for you

```
 ion-item {
     border-radius: 30px !important;
     padding-left: 30px !important;
     font-size: 0.9em;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     border: 1px solid #ffffff;
     border-bottom: 0px !important;
     box-shadow: none !important;
 }
```